# Pubnub iOS push notification filtering?

Tags: ios, pubnub

According to [this post](http://www.pubnub.com/community/discussion/77/filter-owner-messages-on-pubnub-data-streams), the best practice is filtering channel messages on client side. I haven't found a feasible way to do that when push notification is integrated yet. Right now our iOS client gets notified for a lot of useless messages when app is not running.

Comment: I received your question on our support system and will answer their. I will post final answer here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Filtering PubNub Messages and Push Notifications

This is a shortcoming with APNS, not PubNub. PubNub works in such a way that all subscribers of a channel receive all messages published on that channel. But when an app is in the background on iOS or not running at all, your app does not have the opportunity to process the push notification before it is displayed by the iOS device. Android/GCM does allow your app to intercept the message before it is displayed.

Fortunately, there is only one scenario (that I can think of) where the sender of a msg would receive their push notification version of the message (meaning, you couldn’t intercept and not display it).

- user publishes msg
- then immediately (quickly) leaves the app (home button, switch to another app, etc)
- push msg appears

But if the user stays in the app for a second or two (or long enough to receive the realtime msg AND the push notification), then you can prevent the push msg from being displayed. But there is no need to filter on UUID because you should be suppressing all push notifications from being displayed when the app is active in the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` delegate, because you already have the realtime message on the subscribe callback.

That [link you referenced (Filter Owner Messages on PubNub Data Streams)](http://www.pubnub.com/community/discussion/77/filter-owner-messages-on-pubnub-data-streams) is only for realtime push notifications and Stephen is calling out a feature that we will be rolling out in the near future which allows you to subscribe to a channel but provide a query that allows you to filter/query condition for the messages on the channel, like, “where uuid != ”, where  is the uuid of the subscriber. Then the subscriber would not receive realtime or push notification messages because the server filters them out for you.

For a good overview of push notifications see [Sending APNS and GCM Messages to Subscribers and Mobile Push Notification Services in One API Call](http://www.pubnub.com/community/discussion/498/sending-apns-and-gcm-messages-to-subscribers-and-mobile-push-notification-services-in-one-api-call)

For complete [push notification setup, configuration and implementation, see the docs for each of our SDKs](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/ios-objective-c/mobile-gateway-sdk-v4).

Also, see my answer that describes [how to use iOS silent push notifications to do on device filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35761950/ios-swift-receive-callbacks-from-data-streaming-service-without-push-notific). Same thing can be done on Android but no need to do anything special because you always get the opportunity to process the push notification before it is displayed.

Comment: Awesome stuff Craig. Is there an estimated timeline for the filtering feature?

Comment: Nothing externally announced, yet. Just keep following @pubnub and https://www.pubnub.com/blog/ for the latest on all upcoming features.