# iOS / Swift : Receive callbacks from data streaming service without push notifications while app is in background

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, apple-push-notifications, pubnub

*The Background Information:*

I am writing an application that uses the PubNub framework to directly couple one Raspberry Pi with one iPhone, for each individual user. The Raspberry Pi uses an Arduino as a slave to gather analog data, then uses the PubNub network to publish that data to the one and only iPhone that is on the same channel. With the data that the iPhone receives, it determines (locally) if the user needs to be alerted. Then, when the user is alerted, they have the ability to adjust the current state of the Raspberry Pi by sending data (settings) back to the Pi, which will then resolve the problem that warranted a user alert.

*The Problem:*

When the iPhone app goes into the background, the messages sent by the Raspberry Pi that the iPhone should be receiving will no longer be caught by the application, and therefor the user is no longer notified when they need to be. The first obvious solution would be to move the logic of what warrants an alert to the Raspberry Pi itself, so that it can use Apple Push Notifications to send those alerts to the user. However, the problem with this is that I am also trying to track whether or not the Raspberry Pi connection has timed out, so that if some unexpected disconnect occurs, the user is notified of that problem as well. This logic *obviously* can not be on the Raspberry Pi itself, because if a disconnect occurs, then it will not be able to push the notification to the iPhone itself. Having a middle man server of sorts to monitor the state of the device would seem like a logical solution... however I ***do not*** want anything other than the iPhone and Raspberry Pi involved in the data transmission and handling, which is clearly the entire motivation behind using PubNub in the first place (within the scope of my application).

This is not a PubNub specific problem. I only cite them to paint a clearer picture. Also worth noting is that I ***do not*** want to fake a location service in order to get iOS to grant continuous background permissions. This is a lazy and sloppy solution with undesired overhead.

*The Question:*

How do I receive (or request) a short string every 15 to 30 seconds in the background to determine if I should throw an alert. This has to be achievable. Based on my research and reading of apple documentation, it is clear to me that many people will try to respond with "it isn't possible." **I do not welcome this answer**. I am here to find a solution that I could not previously find, or that has not previously been proposed. I need an intelligent engineer to propose a genuine solution or workaround to my problem.

I sincerely thank the champion engineer in advance.

Comment: It is important to know if you are planning to publish to the app store or not.  If you are then the answer pretty much is "it isn't possible".  Constant network connection such as you describe is expensive in bandwidth and battery life and so isn't a good idea.  If you are not publishing to the app store then you may be able to use a VoIP background mode socket, but really the solution is a server to do the polling for you; a mobile device isn't very reliable as it may be switched off, out of network coverage, on a plane etc.

Comment: @Paulw11 ... fair enough. My initial intention is to get this up and running for personal use. So I welcome a proposal as to how to manage achieving this for myself for the time being. However I would ideally prefer a solution that could potentially be published to the App Store, because I could see myself taking this app commercial in the future if I can work out kinks such as this.

Comment: From the Apple Store Guidelines:

5.8
Apps that excessively use the network capacity or bandwidth of the APN service or unduly burden a device with Push Notifications will be rejected

Comment: @ChristianAbella ... Thanks for the response. I understand that part of the documentation. However I am looking for what is the equivalent of about 10bytes to be handled every minute. The data cost is so low that I can hardly imagine how this would be considered an unacceptable use of bandwidth or network capacity.

Comment: It is not the size but the frequency of the request. With an app using the network every 15-30 seconds, battery will be drained very quickly. And that is the problem. I suggest you use the model/logic used by Viber or any messaging app.  Pushing update when to the device when you have an update instead of the device pooling your server every 15 to 30 seconds.

Comment: @ChristianAbella that was my original thought. But then how am I supposed to know if my Raspberry Pi is ever disconnected from the data streaming service if it is the one sending the push notifications? That is ultimately where the problem comes from. Is there no way to force wake an app or have it run a process even less frequently? What if I poll every 5 minutes. It's not like that is outside of the spectrum of frequency of use that a normal user would require from their phone.

Comment: Not to mention, how is querying for info every 30 seconds any worse than receiving a push notification containing info every 30 seconds. What is to stop me from bombarding the app with that many notifications?

Comment: It isn't.  Pushing every 30 seconds is also awful.  Don't try and make a mobile device do something a server should do.  A server would  (presumably) have pretty good network connectivity so it is well placed to do missing event detection.  It also doesn't have bandwidth or power restrictions.

Comment: What is the best server to use for activity such as this without owning one myself. Would parse do the trick?

Comment: Parse is going away and also background jobs are limited.  I don't know if you will find anything for free.  You don't really need a 'server' in terms of hardware.  A cheap laptop running Linux on a home broadband connection would do it.  If you want greater reliability then you will have to pay; You can use AWS, Azure, etc or just rely on the RasPi

Comment: Well technically speaking the raspberry Pi is already a Linux box running on my home network. The only thing that prevents me from being completely satisfied with the Pi handling all the push notification logic is that I won't know if the Pi disconnects while my iPhone app is in the background. If I wasn't trying to ensure that I get a notification in that specific situation, then I'd be perfectly happy with the Pi itself handling all push notifications.

Comment: I guess what it comes down to you is how much is reliability worth?  You can run on the Pi at home for free, but if you want something in the cloud it is going to cost $.  Is the $ < cost of a missing notification?  You also need to consider that push notifications aren't guaranteed (although they are pretty reliable).

Comment: Fair enough. Out of curiosity how much battery are we really talking about here if I forced the app to run constantly with VoIP for personal use only.  I'm not very familiar with that process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@JonW I read your question, and some of the comment until I got to the TL;DR point :) The short answer is that *silent push notifications* might be the answer to one of your problems.The other might be *PubNub Presence Webhooks*. But I would agree with @Paulw11 that a server is the best practice and ultimately, [PubNub BLOCKS](https://www.pubnub.com/products/blocks/) will be your solution.

### Background Processing with Apple Silent Push Notifications

To do some short background processing, you can have your RPi publish a message that includes a push notification (as I believe you are already doing). But this push msg should be a [silent push notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH107-SW1). The docs say this:

> When a silent notification arrives, iOS wakes up your app in the
> background so that you can get new data from your server or do
> background information processing.
>
> ... ensure there is no alert, sound, or badge payload in the aps dictionary

The full details are at the link I just provided but here is a sample message payload that you would publish on PubNub with the proper `aps` format.

```
{
    "pn_apns": {
        "aps": {
            "content-available": 1,
            "data": {
                "temperature": "55",
                "humidity": "42%"
            }
        }
    },
    "data": {
        "info": "This is the full realtime message.",
        "temperature": "55",
        "humidity": "42%"
    }
}
```

*WARNING: The silent push notifications are only effective if the app is not in a kill state. In other words, it must be idle in background - not running, but idle. If you force kill the app (swipe up from recent apps list by double tap Home button) or do not start the app after device has been powered off then on again, then silent pushes will be ignored.*

See this [Badge Count Demo](https://github.com/pubnub/badgeCountDemo) as a template for getting started. But as @Paulw11 said, regular push notifications every 30 seconds is not a good idea. You should be sending your updates to a server that can send a push notification to the iPhone app when it is necessary to take action.

### Offline Notification with PubNub Presence Webhooks

Going further down the server process best practice, you can have your server monitor the *presence* of the RPi on the channel. If the RPi ever *leaves* the channel by explicit unsubscribe from channel (`leave` event) or by network disconnect (`timeout` event), then a message can be `POST`ed to your server REST endpoint (that you provide us to configure on your PubNub keys). If either of these events happens, then you can publish a message (silent push payload included) to your iPhone app to take appropriate action.

### PubNub BLOCKS - No Server Required (Look mom, no server!)

So you say you want to avoid using a server. With [PubNub BLOCKS](https://www.pubnub.com/products/blocks/), you will be able to avoid using your *own* server - instead, you will use *PubNub servers*.

I won't into too much details here, but you will be able to write a small bit of JavaScript in a *BLOCK* that can determine if a push notification needs to be sent or not and much much more.

### Summary

For now, I think your prototype with silent push is good to flesh out your use case. But ultimately, you need to have an always on process that can determine when it is necessary to send a push notification. While your iPhone app is active, it can receive the realtime messages from RPi, but when in background, getting a silent push every 30 seconds is not ideal and possibly not allowed by Apple.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. It gave me the clarification I was looking for. It appears that BLOCKS is not released yet? I wasn't able to find an expected roll out date, or pricing info. Do you mind posting that information or a link to where it can be found?

Comment: It is in early access right now, which you can sign up for. No hard dates for release, yet.